# Maven depedency for opencv_contrib

Tags: java, opencv, setup-project, maven-dependency, opencv-contrib

I have searched and tried many dependencies, but noone of the tried could help me load the OpenCV Face module correctly. Is there one? Or I have to import it locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used bytedeco/JavaCV, and it worked out well. Here is the maven dependency :

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacv-platform</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

[Link to the JavaCv library](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv)